# How to remove hover of logo in header

Tags: css, wordpress, header, hover

Right now I try to create the following web page: https://wpjelly.com/shave/

Can someone help me, how I can disable the (blurry) hover effect of the logo in the center?
I still want to keep the hover effect of the menu and dropdown menu, but want to get rid of it of the logo. I already tried to add some CSS, but all didn't work.

Thank you very much in advance!

Kind regards,
Jonas

Comment: Please show your relevant code instead posting a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo has `opacity: 0.6` set when being hovered.
Set it to `1`:

```
#site-header.center-header #site-navigation-wrap .middle-site-logo:hover img {
-moz-opacity: 1;
-webkit-opacity: 1;
opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer! Is is my third day working with WP, so sorry for the maybe silly question, but can I copy "#site-header.center-header #site-navigation-wrap .middle-site-logo:hover img" or do I have to change something?

Comment: @Jonmue Yes, you can copy this, because I copied the code from your website. If it solves your problem, consider marking my answer as "accepted". [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Anrey Thanks, it worked. >ou're the best! One last question: https://wpjelly.com/jonas6/ Here I have the same problem. I tried it with your way but it didn't work, I don't really know what comes before {...]. Could you help me with that?

Comment: @Jonmue change it to `#site-logo #site-logo-inner a:hover img`

Comment: thank you very much for both advices! Both logos are now without hover effect, brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

set the opacity to 1
and remove the transitions

```
#site-logo #site-logo-inner a img {
    width: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    **webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
     transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;**
```